# How to get trusted SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, certificate

I want to secure my symfony2 application with https. I followed an instruction how to create a SSL certificate and SSL is working but Firefox says this page is not trusted. Same for Safari.

How to get a trusted SSL certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question correctly, you would need to provide more information about the certificate itself:

- Is the certificate a wildcard one, and if it is, does your hostname that you are using on the site have the same subdomain level as the wildcard certificate? Wildcard certificates support only the single subdomain level matching.

  *.example.com certificate would support www.example.com but not dev.web.example.com
- Normally the certificate you have created should be signed by the respective certificate authority, but I presume you have already done that.
- Click on site information in Firefox https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-tell-if-my-connection-is-secure and provide here the information about the certificate. What you would need to provide here is how many bits are in the RSA key, what encryption was chosen (TLS1.x, SSHv3)

Comment: The certificate is signed by myself. Which "respective certificate authority" is out there to sign certificates? I just want to have encrypted transfer on my application...

Comment: You are getting the error because your certificate is self-signed. There are a few sites that offer to sign the certificate you produced. One of them is https://www.globalsign.eu/ but you can find others as well there. They also offer step-by-step procedure to get things done. If that works for you please accept my answer.